# How to fix this 'Missing assembly reference' error?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, uwp, inkcanvas

I am working on an application that captures real time pen strokes on a canvas using *Wacom Bamboo Slate*. The application is being developed for UWP platform using C#. After drawing on the canvas, save feature is to be implemented. I am using [this](https://edi.wang/post/2017/3/2/windows-10-uwp-save-inkcanvas-to-picture) for my reference. Below is the code and error message:

```
private async void BtnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            StorageFolder storageFolder = KnownFolders.SavedPictures;
            var file = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("sample.jpg", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

            CanvasDevice device = CanvasDevice.GetSharedDevice();
            CanvasRenderTarget renderTarget = new CanvasRenderTarget(device, (int)inkCanvas.ActualWidth, (int)inkCanvas.ActualHeight, 96);

            using (var ds = renderTarget.CreateDrawingSession())
            {
                ds.Clear(Colors.White);
                ds.DrawInk(inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.GetStrokes());
            }

            using (var fileStream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
            {
                await renderTarget.SaveAsync(fileStream, CanvasBitmapFileFormat.Jpeg, 1f);
            }
        }
```

> CS1061 'InkCanvas' does not contain a definition for InkPresenter and no accessible extension method InkPresenter accepting a first argument of type InkCanvas could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I have figured out the reason for error but have no insight on how to solve it. The link that I am using for reference uses inkcanvas (a part of Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.InkCanvas) and the inkcanvas that I am using is a part of SDK provided by Wacom(Wacom.UX.InkCanvas).

Comment: In Visual Studio check menu "Project > Manage Nuget Packages" and "Project > <your project> Properties".

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered:

```cs
RenderTargetBitmap rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)inkCanvas.Width, (int)inkCanvas.Height, 96d, 96d, PixelFormats.Default);
rtb.Render(inkCanvas);
```

After which you can then:

```cs
JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(rtb));
encoder.Save(fileStream);
```

Comment: Didn't work. RenderTargetBitmap does not contain a constructor that takes 5 arguments.

Comment: I used: `public RenderTargetBitmap (int pixelWidth, int pixelHeight, double dpiX, double dpiY, System.Windows.Media.PixelFormat pixelFormat);`, ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.rendertargetbitmap.-ctor

Answer (score 0):

The sample referred above can be found [here](https://github.com/EdiWang/UWP-Demos/tree/master/UWPInkCanvasSaveJpg).

The sample use `CanvasDevice` from the `Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas` namespace part of the package `Win2D.UWP` (version 1.6.0) from Microsoft. The UWP project sample targets build 10240 (minimum 10240) of Windows 10.

The package `Win2D.UWP` can be installed

- using the menu "Project > Manage Nuget Packages", or
- by selecting the context menu "References" in the UWP project of "Solution Explorer".

  1. Select "Installed" and uninstall the current 2d graphics rendering package, if any.
  2. Select "Browse", look for `Win2D.UWP` and install the one from Microsoft.

Please note that the latest version of `Win2D.UWP` updated 5/17/2018 version 1.23.0 requires target platform to be 17134.

For example, "Error List" might show the following error message after a build with version 1.23 of `Win2D.UWP` and target version set to 10240 in the UWP project properties:

```
This version of Win2D requires Windows SDK >= 10.0.17134.0, but TargetPlatformVersion is 10.0.10240.0.
```

Target version can be changed in the UWP project properties

- select menu "Project > projectname Properties", or
- by selecting the context menu "Properties" from the UWP project in "Solution Explorer".

PS: Add the following after `InitializeComponent();` in `MainPage.xaml.cs` to enable drawing with a selection of input device types:

```
MyInkCanvas.InkPresenter.InputDeviceTypes = CoreInputDeviceTypes.Mouse | CoreInputDeviceTypes.Pen | CoreInputDeviceTypes.Touch;
```